# Comparing structs in C++

Tags: c++, class, comparison

So in C++ There's a lot of times where you need to make an "index" class. For example:

```
class GameID{
   public:
      string name;
      int regionid;
      int gameid;
      bool operator<(const GameID& rhs) const;
}
```

Now, if we were to represent GameID as `pair<string, pair<int, int> >`, the operator comparison just comes with it. Is there any other way to get that automatic operator comparison without having to use std::pair<> ?

Answer (score 6):

You get an `operator<` when you use `std::pair` because `std::pair` implements an `operator<` overload.  It works when you use `std::string` as one of the types in the pair because `std::string` also overloads `operator<`.

If you want to be able to compare objects of your own class type, you need to overload `operator<` as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the elements in the struct or class that you are defining here you will need to define your own operator overload for ">" or "<" depending on the way you want to compare them.

For example you could do something like this:

```
class GameID{
   public:
      string name;
      int regionid;
      int gameid;


      inline bool operator > (Game_ID first_game, Game_ID second_game)
      {
          return (first_game.gameID() > second_game.gameID());
      }

}
```

As pointed out in the comment by Martin, the standard functions algorithms define things in terms of operator<. So if you define operator < and operator == the other relational operators can be defined via these and as such the standard libs provide the extra functionality to do so automatically.

Comment: All the standard functions algorithms define things in terms of operator<. If you define operator < and operator == all the other relational operators can be defined via these two and as such the standard libs provide the extra functionality to do so automatically.